# Equality between two norms on $\mathcal{L}(E)^n$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-norms

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

On $\mathcal{L}(E)^n$, we have two equivalent norms:
\begin{eqnarray*}
N_1({\bf A})
&=&\sup\left\{\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\|A_kx\|^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}},\;x\in E,\;\|x\|=1\;\right\},
\end{eqnarray*}
and
$$N_2({\bf A})=\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\|A_k\|^2\bigg)^{1/2},$$
for every ${\bf A} = (A_1,...,A_n) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^n$

> In general $N_1\neq N_2$. If $A_iA_j=A_jA_i$ for all $i,j$, is
>   $$N_1=N_2?$$
>   If the claim is false, under which conditions we have $N_1=N_2?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quite an obvious counterexample, take $A_k$ to be the orthoprojector $E\ni x:=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto x_ke_k\in E$ on $E:=\mathbb{C}^n$. Then $A_iA_j=A_jA_i=\delta_{ij}A_i$ but $N_1(A)=1$ and $N_2(A)=\sqrt{n}$.

On the positive side, I think $A_k:=f_k(A)$ with $A$ self-adjoint, and *increasing* functions $f_k:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ should work, even if they don't necessarily commute between them.

Comment: Please in the case of two normal operators which commute, is the two norms are equal? Thanks.

Comment: You may take $n=2$ in the above example.